# Charset UTF-8 doesn't work (stuck with these ?-marks)

Tags: html, css, unicode

I have a Unicode problem... I´ve done this before but for now, I cannot understand
why the Icelandic letters don´t show up - I have those question marks again

Here is the url (very plain and short html5)
http://nicejob.is/new/

Everything I Google says: use the `<meta charset="utf-8">` as I do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: seams like it is not `UTF8` but `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: The link http://nicejob.is/new/ is broken!

Answer (score 15):

Your page is already *viewed* as UTF-8. But your source code is not *saved* as UTF-8.

Please change the encoding of your source code file to UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

Not all browsers support HTML5-way tags yet

[here](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/MetaCharsetAttribute) you can see table of compability

Try this instead:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Actually **all** browsers support `<meta charset=...>` because a lot of people were screwing it up anyway. That's why it became a standard.

Comment: @Innuendo: the link you provided is broken

Answer (score 3):

I can see a couple of issues.

1. The META should look like this:

   `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`
2. The `<html>` specified `lang="en"` which might be prone to confusing some browsers.

Comment: I replaced with your code but still don´t work

I also removed the html lang en

Comment: downvoted for not paying attention to the original question. Ingþór clearly stated that HTML5 is being used. `http-equiv` is the old pre-HTML5 way of specifying the HTML's charset. HTML5 does away with that bloated syntax and introduces the new `charset` attribute that Ingþór showed.

Comment: Fair enough. Though the HTML doc itself does not specify HTML 5 for the doc type, and I read the HTML 5 in the question as being a reference to the URL, not the document.  And how does this differ from the answer directly above, which has 2 upvotes and no down votes?

Comment: Yes, the HTML doc does specify HTML5 is being used.  The very first line of the file is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which is the newer HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 1):

When I view the HTML from the browser, the question marks are encoded as 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD, which is the UTF-8 encoding for the byte order mark or BOM, aka U+FEFF.  So, for whatever reason, the HTML is not transmitted as sensible UTF-8 (though it does seem to be valid UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to save the file with utf-8 encoding by using Notepad (the attached one with Windows).

Steps:

- Save as ..
- In the below options ... you will find encoding option choose UTF-8 ...
- And save the file ...
- Then add the line `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` inside your file ...

And it will work.

Comment: Are you sure the OP is using Windows?

Comment: What do you mean by OP :-|

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using some text editor like notepad++, 
and you didn't **set up encoding to UTF-8 in that text editor**.